# Autogenerate ID in stored procedure -SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio

I have this stored procedure in SQL Server which I use in visual net to generate values for some table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE grabardatos
@codigocliente  int,
@nombre  varchar(50),
@apellido varchar(50),
@sexo char(1),
@direcion varchar(50),
@telefono varchar(50),
@tipo varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO CLIENTES(Numero,Nombre,Apellido,Sexo,Direcion,Telefono,Tipo)

VALUES ( @codigocliente,@nombre,@apellido,@sexo,@direcion,@telefono,@tipo)

END
```

The parameter `@codigocliente` is the id of the table which, according to this code, has to be entered manually in visual net. How Can the id be autogenerated in the sql code of the stored procecure instead of being entered manually in visual net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **clientes** table has an identity key, it will be automatically generated by SQL as part of the INSERT. You can then use `@@identity` to retrieve it's value.

The add the key to the table, you need to create a column

```
ALTER TABLE Add IdKey INT IDENTITY(1,1)
```

Note that during the INSERT, you cannot provide a value for this column...

Comment: Numero is the ID of the table. So, dyou mean that if I modify the stored procedure without @codigocliente as a parameter the id will be generated automatically?.

Comment: It depends on whether or not numero has the IDENTITY attribute.  You need to set that up in SQL first, and if you do, you will not need to pass the @codigocliente parameter

Comment: Sure, the numero is already set up as the IDENTITY attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Then remove numero from the list and remove @codigocliente.  After you INSERT statement, add  SELECT @@identity and the stored procedure will return the newly added key

Comment: @Sparky NO, do NOT use `@@IDENTITY`. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or the `OUTPUT` clause.

Comment: Take Aaron's advice, switch to SCOPE_IDENTITY().